# My file still running but it isn't supposed to

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to import a file in a function and it didn't stop running when it is supposed to. Here is part of my code:

```
def imp():
    root.withdraw() #"root" is the window I created earlier in the code
    import file1 #some tkinter stuff
    root.deiconify()
 
but=tk.Button(root,text='Run',command=imp)
but=pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
```

After ckicking the button and closing the window in "file1.py", "root" dosen't pop back up. Does anyone know why? I cannot figure out a way to solve it, anyone please help.

Sorry if I made anything unclear.

Comment: Where is `root.mainloop()` ? It might also be because your "file1.py" isnt closed properly, without the mainloop? or some mistake while formatting

Comment: What are the contents of your file1.py file? importing a file during a function isn't a recommended way to run some code. Would be better to call a function from the file1.py file

Comment: If `file1` has created another `Tk()` and executed another `mainloop()`, then the `mainloop()` in `file1` will not return even though the `Tk()` window in `file1` is closed.  It is because by default `mainloop()` will return if there is no more instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will try to fit my file1.py in a function.